# Can smoke from small fire cause wiring problems?

Tags: electrical

I had a pretty confined fire in my 
Small enclosed laundry room.  there was a lot of smoke, however. In the low ceiling is a light and i think it now sometimes flickers.  Electrician just looked at the outside of the fixture and said he can tell it's fine because it works.  Im still worried that something is wrong.  Advice? Pretty sure no flzme hit it but it got to 140 degrees and very black smoky.

Answer (score 1):

At only 140 F there should be no problem, 140C on the other hand would have me checking the fixture and wiring insulation to see if anything melted. Most modern homes are wired with NMB wire that is rated for 194F in use (90 C). With the extra heat if an Edison (screw in type lamp) the center contact may have bent away from the lamp causing the flickering. With the power off remove the lamp and using a small screwdriver or other tool reach in and lightly lift the center metal tab, it won't take much and lifting two much can cause the tab to break (1/16 of an inch should be plenty) replace the lamp and see if that fixed the problem. Just a note that if this is a can light recessed in the ceiling they have thermal safety's that do go bad especially if a larger wattage lamp is used (larger than the fixture was designed and listed for)

Comment: Yes 140F. Same electrician does not want to instsll my washer in unfinished  basement using a GFI even though i keep reading it is required and I definitely want it so im just confused overall

Comment: Also do you think the smoke could have corroded the wires?

Comment: I think I would find a new electrician. If you wanted GFCI's on every branch circuit in the house the electrician may tell you why some circuits may have problems but should proceed with the work you want. I have done things in the past that were not good ideas but code legal then because I had explained what might happen got the job to convert back. Just wondering is this electrician licensed? Almost missed smoke, I doubt the smoke could have damaged the wires but heavy soot could cause a minor carbon path in extreme cases

Comment: He must be lisenced even if he didnt renew lately. We built our house and he was the electrician not working under anyone at all so i think we would not have gotten our CO or even electrical permit.  The GFCI is code as far as I know though i plan to call my town. I read something i have to admit not understanding that seemed to say new washers don't trip as much because of some change

Comment: also I'm overly cautious and never use higher wattage bulbs   most fixtures i have are 60 watt max and that's all I use. Hate to break the stack exchange rules but have to say thanks for you help.